# html css icon in ballon

Tags: html, css, icons

I have this in CSS:

```
.capslock { background-image:url('../icon/bullet_error.png') no-repeat center left; padding:2px; padding-left:20px; font-weight:700 !important; }
```

and I have this in html:

```
'<div class="capslock">Caps Lock está ligado</div>'
```

But it gives me this:
[image: Caps Lock Ballon]

it should have an icon before 'Caps Lock está ligado'.
What am I doing wrong?
(the path for the icon is correct)

Comment: should be "background: ...." not "background-image: ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are defining more than a background image with this style you need to use background: ... rather than background-image: ...